# Why are /var/cache and /var/log created as www-data user (shopware6)

Tags: linux, installation, apache2, shopware6

Why does Shopware installer (version 6.4.14.0, dedicated Ubuntu 18.04) is using www-data user as an owner of the resources in /var/cache and /var/log directories, even though the user that is running apache is different? 
 
When I upload the package and try to install it I've got following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the "cache" directory (/var/www/shopware/var/cache/prod_h9d31c36e0ebc8a2d9604631b55f50e36). in /var/www/shopware/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:638 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/shopware/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(545): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() #1 /var/www/shopware/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php(191): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() #2 /var/www/shopware/vendor/shopware/recovery/Install/src/app.php(46): Shopware\Core\Kernel->boot() #3 /var/www/shopware/vendor/shopware/recovery/Install/index.php(74): getApplication() #4 /var/www/shopware/public/recovery/install/index.php(6): require_once('...') #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/shopware/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php on line 638
```

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to write in the "logs" directory (/var/www/shopware/var/log). in /var/www/shopware/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:641 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/shopware/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(545): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() #1 /var/www/shopware/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php(191): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() #2 /var/www/shopware/vendor/shopware/recovery/Install/src/app.php(46): Shopware\Core\Kernel->boot() #3 /var/www/shopware/vendor/shopware/recovery/Install/index.php(74): getApplication() #4 /var/www/shopware/public/recovery/install/index.php(6): require_once('...') #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/shopware/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php on line 641
```

After changing the permission (777) for /var/cache and /var/log installer starts, and it creates directory and file that are owned by www-data 
 [Terminal][1]

Is there some env variable that installer use to perform above actions as a www-data user? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of questions.

- Why does Shopware installer ... apache is different?

  - Apache often runs as www-data. What user is your apache running?
- Is there some env variable ... can I find it?

  - This is a quit general question. Would be possible. But, I did not often see this. Execute `set` in a terminal an see all of the env variables.

Comment: Apache was running as shopware user.<br/> I couldn't find anyenv variable that could set www-data user so I assume that it is somewhere in Shopware application.